# How to download an image from website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I'd like to download a particular region of website as screenshot.png. I tried to define element but python gives me this error:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/gribe/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 25, in 
element = driver.find_element_by_id('highcharts-43')
File "C:\Users\gribe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "C:\Users\gribe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\gribe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\gribe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="highcharts-43"]"}
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)"

---

From website I studied chart location and id but it was not sufficient. Could you give me any advice about this topic?

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

element = driver.find_element_by_id('highcharts-43')
location = element.location
size = element.size
print(location)
print(size)
#
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']


im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

---

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the HTML element?

Comment: Hi Matteo, this is the xpath I can trace: "//*[@id="highcharts-43"]. It is the graph reported below in the page "https://www.plus500.it/Instruments/TSLA"

Comment: I mean something like this: <img id = 'highcharts', src='https://example.com'>

Comment: <div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-12" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 517px; height: 280px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0.333328px;

Comment: where is the img that you want to download?

Comment: I think it's "highcart-12" inside div class highcharts-container. I'm not sure, but if you could help this hyperlink "plus500.it/Instruments/TSLA" you can see the image is the graph of Tesla stock ticker reported scrolling down. I don't know if I answer yuor question correctly